# How do I properly set up client side routing for angular 2.0/spark single page app?

Tags: url, angular, single-page-application, angular2-routing, spark-java

I am using [spark](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#getting-started) as a backend to an [angular 2.0](https://angular.io/) application that I am developing.

I am serving my initial index.html like so, using spark.

```
import spark.Spark.*;

public class Browser {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        staticFiles.location("/public");
        get("/hello/", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
    }

}
```

This is working fine for my initial serving of the index.html

However, now I am attempting to set up some client side routing. Largely following along with [this tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) with some minor variations.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MetadataDisplayComponent } from './metadata-display.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path : '', redirectTo: '/metadata/', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path : 'metadata/:path', component: MetadataDisplayComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
}) 

export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

Now, if I navigate my browser URL bar to "localhost:8050", then then index.html will be served, and the client side code will display my "MetadataDisplayComponent", after being redirected. For this reason, I know my component is being imported/used correctly.

However, if I put, say "metadata/foo", in my browser URL bar, I will get a 404 error. I believe this is because I do not have a route

```
metadata/foo
```

On my spark backend. But I would like the app to still load the index.html as before, and then call the client side's routing to switch the the appropriate component.

How do I set up my app so that I can input urls into the browser url bar, only load the initial index.html, and have the client side routing take over from there?

EDIT
[This article](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/deep-dive-into-client-side-routing-navigo-pushstate-hash) seems to articulate my problem well enough. I need a way to make every request to my backend redirect to the same index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can benefit from a [feature added in version 2.5.4 of Spark](https://twitter.com/sparkjava/status/806214505042681856), the custom 404 and 500 error pages. Just return to a page that redirects to where you want.